# System IOException Stream Read End with Sharp SSH

Tags: c#, ssh, sftp, sharpssh

I'm currently facing a really strange problem in one of my projects.

I've implemented Tamir Gal's Sharp SSH Library in my code to upload some files per FTP.
When I run the code in Debug Mode everything works just as it should. But when I build the solution and try it with that built version, I get a System.IO.IOException:

```
Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: System.IO.IOException: End of IO  Stream Read at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.IO.getByte(Byte[] array, Int32 begin, Int32 length)
at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.Session.read(Buffer buf)
at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.User.Auth.start(Session session)
at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.UserAuthNone.start(Session session)
at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.Session.connect(Int32 connectTimeout)
at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.Session.connect(Int32 connectTimeout)
at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.SshBase.ConnectSession(Int32 tcpPort)
at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.SshBase.Connect(Int32 tcpPort)
at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.SshBase.Connect()
```

It looks like there's a Problem with the Data Stream (Hello Captain Obvious! :) ), so the Program doesn't even establish to finish the Connect Method. I just don't get why everything works while debugging. The dlls get copied correctly in the building process.

The code looks like this:

```
sftpClient = new Sftp(this.ftpHost, this.ftpUser, this.ftpPassword);
sftpClient.Connect();
```

All the variables have the correct values and I can connect to the SFTP server using them in a client like Filezilla.

If anybody could give me a hint or has had a similiar problem, I would be very thankful for every comment.

Thank you all in advance and have a nice day.

Comment: I had to test SSH using sharpsshtest.exe on a 2008r2 server after doing that this issues was fixed for me. Must need to register that dll or something to that effect.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My colleague just found the solution:

In SharpSSH you have 3 Dlls:

- Org.Mentalis.Security.dll
- Tamir.SharpSSH.dll
- DiffieHellman.dll

Because I never had to reference Org.Mentalis.Security.dll in the code i totally forgot to copy it during the build process. Because of this the whole Security Layer which SharpSSH relays on wasn't accessible and that's what caused the error.

I hope this thread can help a few other oblivious people. :)

Comment: I used to do some work updating SharpSSH. I have a version that has everything in one DLL @ https://bitbucket.org/mattgwagner/sharpssh . I would also highly recommend you look at SSH.net on Codeplex for a far better, and maintained, SSH library.